# Experience Analytics dashboard gives errors

Tags: xdb, sitecore-client, xconnect, experience-analytics

[image]

My Logs shows this error

```
2428 23:47:09 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
URL http://ffg.local/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/786FBA3A4573445EA74504E3CA5E48C1/all?&dateGrouping=by-week&&dateFrom=23-04-2019&dateTo=23-07-2019&keyGrouping=collapsed

Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.c.b__4_1(SegmentDefinition d)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
```

All my certificates are good and I am able to access the xconnect site without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate of xconnect website faces a trust issue due to presence of non self signed certificate in trusted root certificates in MMC .

In power shell administrator mode try to run below command to check how many certificate are in trusted root folder .

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}
```

Try to move them to CA

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-
Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

Another reason might be certificate thumbprint mismatching.

In IIS Manager check the certificate is set for xConnect websites. Set the proper certificate from the list for xconnect website.

[image]

Check the thumbprint of the certificate and try to place the thumbprint value in the intepub xconnect website App_Config folder `appsetting.config`, `connectionstring.config` file.

`<add key="validateCertificateThumbprint" value="YOUR THUMB PRINT VALUE" />`

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced similar issue and I fixed that by doing some investigation like below:

1. Check if the certificates are present and valid in the xconnect site. If it is invalid or expired, generate those and assign it to the site bindings.
2. Check if the xconnect site is accessible through HTTPS.
3. Delete the Non-SSL certificate from Root.
4. Check if the sitecore services({siteprefix}.xconnect-IndexWorker, {siteprefix}.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService) are running.
   Verify the thumbprint value for all the client certificate references configured in ConnectionStrings.config file and it should match the certificate found in MMC.

Please check this blog for more information
[Analytics Dashboard issue](https://sitecoretravel.blogspot.com/2021/06/errors-on-sitecore-experience-analytics.html).

Hope this might help someone facing similar issue in future.